# EditorConfig: applying rules to multiple, specific folders

Tags: editorconfig

Let's say I have a project with the following folders:

```
/
  /folder1
  /folder2
  /folder3
  /folder4
  /folder5
```

### Question

Is there a way to have my `.editorconfig` file at root (`/`) level but only apply the same rules to (all files within) `folder1`, `folder3` and `folder5` but not the other two?

### What I could do (but doesn't seem ideal)

- Have one copy of the `.editorconfig` file within `folder1`, `folder3` and `folder5`. But duplicating it seems very ugly/inconvenient.
- Create an `.editorconfig` within the root folder with all the rules, then another one with just `root = true` within all the "excluded" folders (`folder2` and `folder4`). It's better, but not ideal because we have to remember to do it on every single folder rules should not be applied to (in reality, there may be dozens of them).

### What I would like to (be able to) do

Create an `.editorconfig` at root level, and list the folders rules should be applied to. I didn't find a way to do something like this:

```
[/folder1/**]
[/folder3/**]
[/folder5/**]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
```

Invalid because you cannot combine sections like that.

Or, using the `{s1,s2,s3}` format:

```
[{/folder1/**, /folder3/**, /folder5/**}]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
```

But it doesn't seem to be valid either (only simple file name patterns seem allowed).

Is there any other way to achieve this? I didn't find anything on the docs or elsewhere, but I may have missed something obvious.

Answer (score 5):

It was introduced to [EditorConfig Core 0.11.0](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-core-js/releases/tag/0.11.0) in 2013. The way to do it is as follows ([Source](https://editorconfig.org/)):

```
[{package.json,.travis.yml}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

I tested the following configuration in Visual Studio Code and can confirm it works.

```
root = true

[{packages/**,plugins/**}]
indent_size = 8
```

If this does not work for you, it likely depends on the implementation/client. It's best to make a feature request to support the feature.

Comment: Comma delimited, no spaces. I'm used to the Windows convention of semi-colons, which does not work. And adding spaces for visual separation also causes problems.